# Итератор массива

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток, необходимо для одной задачи использовать итератор, но если я добавляю в него свои методы, кроме next(), hasnext(), remove(), например prevEl(), то в мейне их не видно, что я делаю не так? и как реализовать метод remove с наименьшими затратами ресурсов?

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Test {

```
private static <T> Iterator<T> getIterator(final T[] array) {
    return new Iterator<T>() {
        private int count = array.length;
        private int index = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < count;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (index < count) {
                return array[index++];
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No such element.");
            }
        }

       //для теста пусть будет тоже самое, что и next()
       public T prevEl() {
            if (index < count) {
                return array[index++];
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No such element.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot remove item from array.");
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] integers = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    Iterator<Integer> integerIterator = getIterator(integers);

    while (integerIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(integerIterator.next());
        //System.out.println(integerIterator.prevEl()); не видит этот метод
    }

}
```

}

Comment: В принципе Ваша задачка очень смахивает на реализацию стандартного ArrayList - посмотрите его исходник - думаю должно натолкнуть на правильные мысли (особенно по вопросу remove)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы объявляете тип переменной как `Iterator` и поэтому можете использовать только методы объявленные в данном интерфейсе.   
Для использования расширенных методов Вы должны использовать собственный тип (именованный класс), реализующий итератор и при использовании объявлять и приводить его к Вашему типу:

```
 YourCustomIterator<Integer> integerIterator = (YourCustomIterator<Integer>) getIterator(integers);
```